# no connection with smack api coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am having a problem with the smack API. I have to create a chat and need to send files. 
There is a class for that (`FileTransferManager`) but when I try to initialize it I am getting an error.

CF reports that it doesn't know the arg of the constructor. The arg constructor is a `XMPPConnection` type and when I supply it, this error occurs:

> Unable to find a constructor for class
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferManager that accepts
>   parameters of type ( org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection ).

Here's the code

```
XMPPConnection1 = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection").init("jabber.cz");
FileManager = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferManager").init(XMPPConnection1);
FileManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("yoyonana@jabber.at");
```

Someone to help me please ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you provide cfdump of **XMPPConnection1** and **FileManager** if possible?

Comment: This is always tricky - anything that requires multiple Java objects passed around in CF takes a lot of trial and error. Why do you post (or pastebin) the sample Java code that came with the API - that often has the clues you need (import classes, objects etc).

Comment: @TusharBhaware I sent you on your email the dump

Comment: @sourceamax, Are you trying to be rude? First of all, i didn't get any mail from you and nor do i wish. And you can provide cfdump here on stack overflow by editing your question. If you try to be nice, people will help you. Your first comment got deleted because you were rude in it.